# Combining parts of animations into one

Tags: animation

I'm new to Blender and dabbling on animations. I did some research and found some similar issues, but not the one I'm looking for I guess.

I have 2 premade Mixamo animations, one for "Standing Aim Recoil" and one for "Fast Run".
My problem lies with the fact that my archer needs to run while drawing the arrow. And I've been trying to no avail.

Today I learnt about retargeting thanks to you people but I don't think I can only retarget "the legs" for the animation right?

I tried deleting top part of the "run object" and lower part of the "archer object" and tried to combine them but no dice (probably doing something wrong, something about bones being "not on the same skeleton" or something).

[I added a wetransfer link for the blend file](https://we.tl/t-Pr9Kxw28fm)

[I also added default bare fbx files](https://we.tl/t-ylUkC3njWG)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to find out which bones makes the lower body part move, just select the bone in pose mode and move it and you will find out: Hips does move the whole thing.

[image]

Now we have to find out the same for the upper part. And it is pretty sure Spine2: (with small problems, we solve that later)

[image]

to move them together, we just give this upper body bone a child of constraint to the lower body bone so that it moves with it.

[image]

now we have this little slight problem...so we can solve this with a little bit of vertex group correction:

- select the upper body

[image]

- enter edit mode

[image]

- select spine2

[image]

- click select

[image]

- repeat pressing "select" more until it doesn't select more

[image]

- ...until you get:

[image]

- click on "assign"

[image]

run the animation and enjoy the....

result:

[image]

Comment: wow, thank you so much for the fast reply. I hope it works with the game character, but that's for the unity guys to worry about lol